# Merging arrays in Fortran 77

Tags: fortran, fortran77

I have two arrays: `A = [1 2 3 4]` and `B = [5 6 7 8]`. How can I merge A & B into one array, C,  and then sort C in ascending order? I need to do this in fortran 77.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow!  This isn't a code-writing service; please post examples of what you've tried and the exact problems you have encountered.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for guidance.

Comment: also clarify clearly why you cant use modern fortran.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a naive implementation of the concatenation/sorting algorithm:

```
    program sort
    integer size1, size2, sizeout
    parameter (size1 = 4, size2 = 4)
    parameter (sizeout = size1 + size2)
    integer in1(size1), in2(size1)
    data in1/1,2,4,4/, in2/5,8,7,5/
    integer out(sizeout)

c concatenate arrays 
    do j=1,size1
      out(j)=in1(j)
    enddo
    do j=1,size2
      out(j+size1)=in2(j)
    enddo

c sort the elements of the output array
 4  do j=2,sizeout
       if(out(j).lt.out(j-1)) then
          temp    =out(j-1)
          out(j-1)=out(j  )
          out(j  )=temp
          goto 4
       endif
    enddo

    end
```

Comment: This is some way from Fortran 77 and some way from modern Fortran.  And it isn't legal under any standard.

Comment: @francescalus thank you for noting this. As I mentioned this is a naive implementation compiled with gfortran on my machine. It concatenates two arrays and sorts them in ascending order. Please feel free to edit my answer to make it F77 compliant.

Comment: Either chide OP for trying to use SO as a code-writing service, *or* spoon-feed them. Not both.

Comment: I'm in favor of all other comments here except for the last one, I believe @agentp have not tested the code. The code does sort, if the `goto` is removed it wont sort correctly.